# Mauchly's test not giving significant value

Tags: anova

I have sample size of 51, number of levels is 71. I used One-way Repeated Measures Anova in SPSS. But, Mauchly's test of sphericity fails to give me a significant value (it gives "." result). Why? Can I still use the result of Greenhouse-Geisser significance test?

Comment: Welcome to our site!  You really need to give us more information about your data and model .

Comment: Thank you.
I have a sample size of 52 and a repeated measures of 71 (i.e. 52 individuals answering a set of 71 questions on Likert scale). I do not get any significance value for Mauchley's sphericity test. If I include only 52 repeated measures (i.e. repeated measurements ≤ sample size), I get the significance value for Mauchley's sphericity test. If I include repeated measures value greater than sample size (e.g. repeated measurement ≥ 53), the Mauchley's sphericity test fails to give me a significant value.

Thanks.